# Pass UTC offset into controller route

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, utc, local-variables

Fairly new to ASP.NET CORE, come from WPF background.

Having some trouble understanding how to pass local variables around.

I have a form:

```
<span id="clock"></span>
<form asp-action="Create" asp-controller="Session" method="post" asp-route-session="@Model.Session">
            <input asp-for="@Model.Session.ClientId" class="form-control" style="display: none" />
            <ejs-dropdownlist id="clinics" dataSource="@Model.LinkableClinics" placeholder="Select Clinic" popupHeight="220px" ejs-for="@Model.Session.ClinicId">
                <e-dropdownlist-fields text="Name" value="ClinicId"></e-dropdownlist-fields>
            </ejs-dropdownlist>
            <ejs-dropdownlist id="employees" dataSource="@Model.LinkableEmployees" placeholder="Select Employee" popupHeight="220px" ejs-for="@Model.Session.EmployeeId">
                <e-dropdownlist-fields text="Name" value="EmployeeId"></e-dropdownlist-fields>
            </ejs-dropdownlist>
            <ejs-datetimepicker id="startdatetimepicker" placeholder="Select a date and time" ejs-for="@Model.Session.StartTime"></ejs-datetimepicker>
            <ejs-datetimepicker id="enddatetimepicker" placeholder="Select a date and time" ejs-for="@Model.Session.EndTime"></ejs-datetimepicker>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create Session" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
```

and I would like to add `asp-route-offset` to my form but I can't figure out how to pass a locally calculated variable into this routing.

This is a post, so I can't just use Url.Redirect() custom url builder.

I've also tried to add a hidden field and run a calculation inside the "value"

```
 <input asp-for="@Model.Session.Offset" class="form-control" style="display: none" value="getValue()"/>
```

I'm calculating my offset in my `<script>` section as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = loaded;

    function loaded() {

        var clockElement = document.getElementById("clock");

        function updateClock(clock) {
            clock.innerHTML = new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60;

        }
    }
</script>
```

I've tried setting variables or the `@Model` object here, but nothing seems to want to stick.

Anyone have experience trying to pass a variable like this? Or a better way to pass UTC offset into my timestamp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to mix and match things happening server-side and client-side. Your script which gets the offset runs client-side, after the server has sent the response. Your Razor code runs server-side, before the client has even received the page.

Long and short, if you want to update the value, you have to do it via client-side means, namely JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('#Session_Offset').value = new Date().getTimezoneOffset();
```

You can't use something like `asp-route-offset` at all, because the offset is coming from the client and can't be used to generate the post URL. As a result, you'll need to stick with the hidden input approach.

Comment: Am I able to run a method inside "value" here? How do I insert my value into the hidden field?

Comment: No. Because that method doesn't exist server-side. The way you modify the value is the code I posted in my answer.

Comment: Thank you kindly! Very new, this seems helpful for me going forward in learning.

Comment: I'd encourage you to familiarize yourself with the HTTP protocol (MDN has a nice primer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview) and to a lesser extent REST (https://restfulapi.net/). REST isn't strictly about HTTP, but the principles of REST apply to basically everything that happens on the web. Just like you wouldn't write an iOS app without understanding first how iOS works, you should know how the web works if you intend to design web apps.

Comment: Thanks... this was just how javascript works and not really about REST or HTTP but I'll take the advice anyways.

Comment: The fundamental problem came from not understanding the client-server relationship in HTTP. That is why I made the suggestion.